# Having right and left wrapping floats correctly displayed in the same page

Tags: wrapfigure, rendering

I try to put two images wrapped in the top of the page but in the same line, so I made the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum,tikz}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}[2cm]{0.3\textwidth}
  \vspace{-10pt}
    \includegraphics[width=0.23\textwidth]{example-image}
  \vspace{-10pt}
\end{wrapfigure}


\begin{wrapfigure}{r}[2cm]{0.3\textwidth}
  \vspace{-10pt}
    \includegraphics[width=0.23\textwidth]{example-image}
  \vspace{-10pt}
\end{wrapfigure}

\lipsum[2-18]
\end{document}
```

And this code give me the following ugly rendering:

[image]

But, mysteriously, when I only use the first or the second `wrapfigure` environment, the rendering work fine:

[image]

The problem only appear when I use it twice in the same time in the same page.

So, how can I put on the top of documenter two `wrapfigure` at the same page height?

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this with wrapfigure. The setting of the second will destroy the settings of the first. You need to define your \parshape manually:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum,tikz}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

\parshape 7  0pt            0.75\textwidth 
             0.25\textwidth 0.5\textwidth 
             0.25\textwidth 0.5\textwidth 
             0.25\textwidth 0.5\textwidth 
             0.25\textwidth 0.5\textwidth 
             0.25\textwidth 0.5\textwidth 
             0pt \textwidth  
\noindent\raisebox{-\height}[0pt][0pt]{%
 \makebox[0.25\textwidth][l]{%
  \makebox[\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=0.23\textwidth]{example-image}\hfill \includegraphics[width=0.23\textwidth]{example-image}}}}%
\lipsum*

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting solution, but it didn’t permit to put a part of the graphic in the margin, like we did it with `[2cm]` `wrapfigure`’s option.

Comment: Simply change the value in the raisebox. And for horizontal displacement you can add \hspace to the inner makebox, or use the trim key.